# Exclude category for main query and custom

Tags: wp-query, functions

As you can see, on the second line here, I am effecting the main query only. This would have no effect on custom queries elsewhere on the site. How do you apply it to custom queries too?

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'cat', '-9' );
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts',  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\exclude_category');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom query. In that case, you can pass the parameter directly to the custom query. Otherwise, you can add other conditions in 'exclude_category' function. for instance, You can check whether category, post type, archive or not.